# Location of imported files in R. Special folder or commandlinesyntax

Tags: r, import

I want to import a large excel(.xls) sheet into R by the command matrix = read.xls(statimpo.xls). I have initial preps by installing gdata, loading gdata. The trouble is just i do not know how to make R find the file. I have tried to specify the whole pathway from / to statimpo.xls but no luck. (when i do it in matlab i have a special folder where all imports must be in order to be considered).

Is there another command in order for R to find the file or is there a folder for R i haven't found.

Sincerely

Comment: Try this for an interactive dialog: `myfile <- file.choose(); read.xls(myfile)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getwd()` will give you your working directory - easiest to save the file there, then run your command.

Also, it's not clear from your question, but your command as written doesn't have quotes around the filename, which you need.

Comment: Yes. That made it. also setwd('/path/to/folder') defines the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have quotes around your directory and filename, e.g., `my.matrix <- read.xls ("my.directory/statimpo.xls")`

Or set your working directory with `setwd("my.directory")` and then call `my.matrix <- read.xls("statimpo.xls")`.

If that doesn't work, with your working directory set, troubleshoot by calling in a csv file with the base R `read.csv()` command.  If that works, then your problem might be with the gdata package or the format of your Excel file.